# UIImageView Not Deleting From UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I have created a UITableView with a cell inside. Inside this cell view, we have a Content View, and in that, I have subtitle text. This is all in the storyboard. I wanted to have an image right next to the cell, so I put an image and chose a picture.

The image turned out really small, and I couldn't even make it bigger - it was that small. So I put another image view that I created in the view and plopped it into the tableView. Then I try to delete the first tiny image view. It doesn't delete.

When I try to move it out of the Content View, it duplicates itself. When I try to drag it to the view and out of the Content View, it sends a duplicate version. So I tried to change the cell type from subtitle to custom, hoping that everything in the Content View would disappear and I can put it in again.

Then, Xcode crashed. I tried again with changing it to custom, but it crashed again. I didn't put the crash report because it is very long but tell me in the comments if I should put it, and I will edit this question to put it in. Tell me if there is any other information you need.

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:

I deleted the whole cell. I realized that when putting a picture in the attributes inspector of the table view cell, it makes the picture either really big or really small. It doesn't allow me to resize the picture or move the picture without randomly duplicating it. Does someone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customise the size of your image, you can do so very easily by creating a UINIB file and then customising the look of your cell in the new file created. You can do so by creating a new cocoa touch class of type UITableViewCell and then select the create XIB file checkbox. Then you will see a similar to main.storyboard layout which works exactly like the main.storyboard and the difference is that it is specifically for the table cell. Make sure you register the UINIB with the table view so that you can control the data that shows up in your cell. I hope this helped!

Comment: I'm glad you got the answer you were looking for!

Comment: Thank you! I also just wanted to know if it was possible just in the storyboard without XIB. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can drag and drop labels, images and buttons inside the cells in the storyboard itself... Though it gets harder to configure the data that shows up in the cell.